# Javascript extend object with new keys from other script

Tags: javascript, requirejs, javascript-objects

How can I extend an object with more keys comming from another script?

So I have this require main script, in here I create a general object which I will use throughout the whole project.

Now another script I have is is creating basic project information, which I would like to have into this main object as well

So my require main.js looks like this:

```
//my main object
var mainObj = mainObj || {};

require.config({
    paths: {
        leaflet: './leaflet-0.7.3',
        bootstrap: './vendors/bootstrap.min',
        projectInfo: './project-info'
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
             deps: ['projectInfo'],
             export: 'bootstrap'
         },
    }
});

define(['projectInfo'], function(projectInfo) {

    'use strict';

    mainObj = {

        //HERE I NEED THE PROJECTINFO OBJECTS
        projection: projectInfo.projection,
        version: projectInfo.projection

    };
```

});

Here is the script with the projectInfo:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define([], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory();
    } else {
        factory( root );
    }
}(this, function () {

    return {

        projection: {
            type: 'EPSG:4326',
            proj4: '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs',
            resolutions: [1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5],    
            tilesMap: 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            tilesSat: 'http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'

        },
        version: '0.0.1'

    };

}));
```

This works, howeverdon't want to have to 'copy' the information by hand, I rather just extend this mainObj with this information in one go / one line.

Is there a way to do this without having to write another script to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Underscore's [extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) function:

```
_.extend(mainObj, projectInfo);
```

jQuery has an [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) function, too:

```
$.extend(mainObj, projectInfo);
```

And, as Felix pointed out below, this feature is planned for ES6 with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
Object.assign(mainObj, projectInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks!, but what if you are not using underscore?

Comment: @BonifatiusK: [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Comment: @BonifatiusK: You could also use jQuery's [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) function.

Comment: @FelixKling: That's cool, I had no idea that was part of the ES6 proposal. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: tnx Felix thats a nice one! 
Could somebody post all the correct answers above in one post so I can set that as the one which solved the problem? I am now using the jQuery version by the way.